# PHP Simple Dom Parser - Get value from SPAN

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I'm trying to figure it out, but I don't quite get it I think. Hopefully someone can help me.

[image: Span element]

The value I want to get is from the class "class=time-value js-minutes"

My code

```
function vakantieVeilingHuidigeTijd($url){
  $url = file_get_html($url);
  $huidigeTijdMinuut = $url->find('span[class=time-value js-minutes]');
  echo "Minuten te gaan : " . $huidigeTijdMinuut . "<br>";
  var_dump($huidigeTijdMinuut);
  print_r($huidigeTijdMinuut);
  return $huidigeTijdMinuut;
}
```

The output I get:

[image]

Giving me an empty array, help is welcome thank you.

Answer (score 0):

time-value and js-minutes are two different classes. You have to use only one of these to access the content. Use the one which is unique, example

```
$huidigeTijdMinuut = $url->find('span[class=time-value]');
```

Or

```
$huidigeTijdMinuut = $url->find('span[class=js-minutes]');
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer, unfortantly I get a NULL back (the array is 0)

Comment: Sorry for another comment but I did echo the whole webcontent, and apperently it doesn't grab the JavaScript thus meaning I can't get the data (since the timer is handled by JavaScript) makes sense now that it comes back with 0 results.

Comment: Try using this instead of simple html dom parser: https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs